# Testing streaming service (like selenium)

Tags: selenium, testing, twitch

Good afternoon.

I'm testing my company's streaming service, which works like twitch.

The task is as follows:
Log in to your account and simulate viewing the stream ( and chat)

I was thinking of writing code in selenium. But as far as I understand, in this case you will have to use your own driver for each thread. I'm afraid it will take up too much memory.

Now the question.
It's true? Is there a way to avoid this?
What methods would you recommend to solve this problem?

I just came up with the idea to try not drawing videos to save resources. But there is one caveat here, so that the streaming service doesn't think I'm a bot.
In other words, I have to constantly get it, but not draw it.
This won't work with selenium.

The question is as follows: is it possible
to send login data to the form and "view" the stream programmatically in Java?
Which libraries should I use?

Can you recommend the necessary libraries with links to the functionality I need?

Comment: I can`t edit my question but i take issue.
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-http-live-media-streaming-hls-jmeter
This link help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a service for cloud-hosted testing for this, you will not have to care about the testing infrastructure then. Some services allow you to use Selenium in the test scripts, so test creation will be similar to a local testing experience.
[Here is a link](https://loadero.com/home/features) to a service that will allow you to achieve what you need and you can run some tests for free there.
Also [here is a step-by-step guide](https://blog.loadero.com/2019/09/12/how-to-start-using-loadero/) to create and set your test.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use Selenium Grid with TestNg.
As long as you need to validate the front end, selenium is the tool, if not 100%, you can simple test using API calls:

1. Log in via API calls
2. Perform a get on desired page and use a html parser to make some validations regarding the front end call
3. API calls to check the chat

Comment: I understand, but if I do this about 1000 times through selenium at the same time, then I think there will be too much load on the RAM.
I thought to try through some library working through a proxy.
But I don't know how it will work and will it?
And I don’t know if it’s possible to simulate a real user through a simple connection through a proxy

Comment: if you need the UI (so, selenium), I don't see other way. If you can check it using API calls, you can achieve your goal using: jmeter, blazemeter etc

Comment: I just had the idea to try not to draw the video to save resources. But there is a caveat here, so that the streaming service does not think that I am a bot.
In other words, I must constantly receive it, but not draw it.
It won't work with selenium.